# BrowserRouter wrapping Routes method not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
// import { createBrowserRouter, createRoutesFromElements, Route, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

// const router = createBrowserRouter(
//   createRoutesFromElements(
//     <Route path='/' element={<App/>}/>
//   )
// )

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {/* <RouterProvider router={router}/> */}
    <Router>
      <Route path='/' Component={App} ></Route> // I have also tried component={App}/Component={<App/>} and all
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I tried to use the method in which Route(s) are wrapped by BrowserRouter, and There is visible items being returned from the App component too but it won't display anything. On the other hand the method i commented out works but why won't the usual one work?

I tried using BrowserRouter method of routing in react using react router dom package and expected to get app component to be shown at / path but nothing displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the react-router-dom v6. Here is how to create routes in latest version:

```js
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

 <Router>
  <Routes
    <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
    // Other routes here
  <Routes>
 </Router>
```

> Notice the use of `element` instead of component and `<Routes>` wrapper

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked for me! also I'd like to know if i can use older versions of react router dom with new projects? would that cause problems?

Comment: Yes probably you can imo